# JQuery AJAX load. div doesn't reload itself or parent div

Tags: jquery

I'm doing this:

```
$(function () {
      $("#but").click(function () {
                $('#bigHtml').load('@Url.Action("SecondPage")');
            }); 
});

<div id="bigHtml">
    <div id="but"></div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work. Am I doing something illegal? (@Url.Action works properly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, use **[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** (emphasize mine):

> Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and **in the future**.

```
$("#but").live('click', function () {
    $('#bigHtml').load('@Url.Action("SecondPage")');
});
```

---

In your code, you are attaching the event handler to the one `#but` instance that is currently in the page. When you reload the content, this instance is removed, also the event listeners. The `#but` element from the new content is a *different instance*.

You are not rebinding the event handler. When the JavaScript code is called, jQuery looks for an element `#but` and is done. It does not look again for that element after you injected new content. `live()` overcomes this problem by not attaching the event handler to the element but the the document root.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work for a first time. Event fires, but load does nothing. After several tests I understood that it is all because event binded to div with "but" id tries to change his parent.

Comment: @user724910: Do you have a link to the page? The code you posted will work as it is (for the first time). See here: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/3tXLK/

Comment: @user724910: You mean my example does not work? That is indeed strange. Make sure you have JavaScript enabled. If you don't provide more information (*does not work* is **not** information) or better, a link to the page in question, I cannot help you more, sorry.

Comment: Exuse me for my undetailed comments. Your example worked in the browser but it didn't work in vs 2010. jquery1.4.4.js is default jquery lib. I updated it to 1.5.2 and it worked! It's very wierd..
By the way now I use live() like you advised me and it all works the way i want
Thanks :)

Comment: @user724910: You're welcome :) The example also works with jQuery 1.4.4 (you can change the version in my example on the left side). I guess VS is just acting weird.... in any way, if it works, it works :) (you should then mark this answer as accepted by clicking the tick outline next to it...)